# Unable to open some Apps on M1- CPU consumptions are 100%

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, crash

I'm currently running macOS Ventura 13.0.1. I cannot open some apps like iterm2 and Mathematica today. I find that after I open these apps, the background CPU consumption reaches 100%, as shown below:
[image]

I tried to reinstall these apps, and restart the computer but nothing helped.

Comment: You say you 'can't open them', and then you say "after I open them". Percentage CPU is usually per core, so on an M1 with 10 cores, you can have 1000% in total. Do you have the most up-to-date (native?) versions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker. I click to open these apps but there's no response. I'm pretty sure that they are up-to-date and native versions and I use them from day to day until a few days ago.

Comment: The problem has been resolved by creating a new account. But I'm worried that it might happen again.

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered that the problem does not appear in a new user account.

Do NOT migrate to the new account; but go back to the old one, and fix it there. (After all, if it happens again, will you keep moving on...?)

A problem specific to one user account means that *something* within the user account is causing the problem. This could be a corrupt or incorrect preference; or some background process that is set to launch, which is causing a conflict. It might even be corrupt caches.

Basically, the problem is somewhere in the user Library folder. I'd suggest emptying caches first, then removing (and testing) any background processes that are set to launch.